# Options for Parsing Excel Files in ExtJS

Tags: node.js, extjs, extjs4

I'm having a very hard time accomplishing my main goal: *extracting data from an xlsx excel file*

I'm running ExtJS + node.js, and I see two options:

1. Use [this XLSX.js framework](http://innovatejs.wordpress.com/2012/08/29/introducing-xlsx-js/) to convert the base64 string into js object-representations of xlsx worksheets for me to use. Problem is, I have no idea how to get a base64 string from an xlsx file..
2. Upload the xlsx file to the server, do the conversions there using [node-xlsx](https://github.com/mgcrea/node-xlsx), the send the object-representations back ala json. Having lots of difficulties here since ExtJS doesn't use real AJAX for file uploads so I don't know how to send the results back..

Has anyone had experience with this or could advise a solution? Having lots of trouble..

Comment: Impossibility to access files (locally or selected by user) from a browser is by design. Security has to be kept as strict as possible. That's why your second option is the only option.

Comment: Do you just need to parse the xlsx file?  If so, might I suggest http://niggler.github.io/js-xlsx/ (`xlsx` on npm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number two is going to be the better option IMO. You can take a look at the FileUploadField control - there is a good example on submitting the Form that will upload the file to the server: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File

From there you can parse and return the json.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying that currently, but I can't find out how to access the response from the server. Using Express 3.x, I respond via `res.json({success: true, response: anObject})`

Comment: .. found it. It's in `action.result.response`

Answer (score 0):

Since we struggled with exactly the same issue, we created a front-end XLS(X) and CSV import and export tool that you can use in ExtJS 4 applications with a few lines of code. The user just drags the file on the grid and done. We just launched it, here is a description of the problematic in dealing with files and the solution: http://2gears.com/2014/08/ext-js-excel-import-export-easy/

Hope it helps.